# How to dynamically split the dataframe based on column count in pandas?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read an excel file with around 780 columns. Once I have read it, I want to split the dataframes dynamically based on the column count and insert it into sql table. As for now, I am able to do it by adding the dataframe manually inside a function. For example, if I want to split it by 250 columns, then I need to create dt variable 4 times to insert into a table.

How do I make it dynamically where it will split the dataframes based on the column count inside the excel file? Below is my code:

```
 def sqlcol(dfparam):    
     dtypedict = {}
     for i,j in zip(dfparam.columns, dfparam.dtypes):
        if "object" in str(j):
            dtypedict.update({i: sqla.types.NVARCHAR(length=255)})

        if "datetime" in str(j):
            dtypedict.update({i: sqla.types.DateTime()})

        if "float" in str(j):
           dtypedict.update({i: sqla.types.Float()})

        if "int" in str(j):
           dtypedict.update({i: sqla.types.BIGINT()})
    
        if "decimal" in str(j):
           dtypedict.update({i: sqla.types.DECIMAL()})
        
    return dtypedict

def import_varchar_to_hst03(db:str,tb_name:str,df):
    n= 1

    import pandas as pd
    import sqlalchemy as sqla
    import urllib
    import pyodbc
    t=sqlcol(df1)
    a=sqlcol(df2)
    c=sqlcol(df3)
    quoted = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE="+db+";Trusted_Connection=yes;")
engine = sqla.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted), fast_executemany = True)
    df1.to_sql(tb_name, schema='dbo', con = engine, index=False,dtype=t,if_exists='replace')
    df2.to_sql(tb_name + ( "A" * n), schema='dbo', con = engine, index=False,dtype=a,if_exists='replace')
    df3.to_sql(tb_name + ( "B" * n), schema='dbo', con = engine, index=False,dtype=a,if_exists='replace')

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Ex=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\sriram.ramasamy\Desktop\Testsriram.xlsx',sheet_name=None)


for sh,v in Ex.items():
    df=pd.DataFrame(v)  
    df1 = df.iloc[:,:255] 
    df2 = df.iloc[:,np.r_[0:1,256:500]]
    df3 = df.iloc[:,np.r_[0:1,501:700]]
    import_varchar_to_hst03('InsightMaster',sh,df)

print('data imported to database')
```